Getting the wrong coordinates through event in React Native
I have a program where, wherever I touch on the screen, I draw a circle. However, when I try to click inside of a created circle to try to draw another circle (which, logically, part of it will be inside of the previous circle), instead the new circle is created way outside of where I want it be to drawn, closeby the 0,0 coordinates, but never exactly
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [circles, setCircles] = useState([]);

  const handlePress = (event) => {
    const { locationX, locationY } = event.nativeEvent;
    const newCircle = { id: circles.length, x: locationX, y: locationY };

    setCircles([...circles, newCircle]);
  };

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={handlePress}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {circles.map(circle => (
          <View
            key={circle.id}
            style={[styles.circle, { left: circle.x, top: circle.y }]}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  circle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
});

export default App;

Any idea on how to make it so any created circles with coordinates occupied by circles get on the correct place?
I've tried to make the created objects both view and touchableopcaity. Neither option worked, it always makes it so the circles get created way above, on top left of the screen
